# Sympy substitutes

Tags: python, sympy, subscript

I am just a new user for SymPy. I am self learning this library for my undergrauate research. But in the middle of the process I am stuck with one code.

I have defined a function with a subscript.

```
U_n= x^n + 1/x^n
```

When I consider `(U_1)^3` I get `(substitute n=1)`

```
(U_1)^3 = (x+1/x)^3
```

Then after simplifying this I get

```
(U_1)^3 = (x^3 + 1/x^3) + 3(x+ 1/x)
```

But one can see this answer as

```
(U_1)^3 =   U_3 + 3U_1
```

How to get the output in terms of U_n 's ?

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import sympify
import sympy
x=symbols('x')
def u(n):
    return x**n+1/x**n

def unu(eq1):
    c = (eq1.subs(x, exp(x))).simplify()/2
    return c.subs(cosh, Function('u')).subs(x,1)


from sympy import *
from sympy import sympify
import sympy
x=symbols('x')
def v(n):
    return x**n-1/x**n

def vnu(eq2):
    c = (eq2.subs(x, exp(x))).simplify()/2
    return c.subs(sinh, Function('v')).subs(x,1)
```

This is my current code.I have built it to 2 separate U_n and V_n.But I cannot combine them.

Can someone please give an idea how to build this code using SymPy. It would be a very big help for my research.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you create runable example code, including data imports and initializations? Are you aware that `^` in sympy only indicates `exclusive or`?

Comment: sorry my bad. I have used ** to take the power in my code. I have created a code with a function but in that function I get my anwers in X terms which is supposed to be. But I want the answer in U_n terms(Back substituting U_n's to X's). Have an idea how to create it?

Comment: Could you edit your post and add runable example code, including data imports and initializations?